# connection between adding an imageView and navBar tintColor?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

This is really weird and I can't seem to be able to explain that. Took me hours to realize that only when I add a UIImageView as a subView to my self.view in the ViewController viewDidLoad then I can set the tint color of my navbar. If I add the UIImageView in the init method - tint color doesnt do anything to my nav bar.

So...

In this case my nav bar is getting the tint color:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//NAV BAR COLOR  
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

//ADDING BACKGROUND IMAGE 
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aaa.png"];
[self.view addSubview: imgView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];

}
```

Here it doesnt (just moved the adding of the image to the init method):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
  //ADDING BACKGROUND IMAGE 
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aaa.png"];
[self.view addSubview: imgView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];    }
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//NAV BAR COLOR  
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

}
```

This is how I call this view:

```
Login *loginViewController = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCntrl1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navCntrl1 animated:YES];
```

Any idea why? I am soo puzzled...thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with your image, it's to do with the way UINavigationControllers are created.

Here's your code (with some comments added) :

```
// Create the view controller
Login *loginViewController = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

// Create a navigation controller and add it
UINavigationController *navCntrl1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
```

`viewDidLoad` is called the first time that the ui needs to know about your view controller's view. If your `viewDidLoad` method wants the edit a feature of a navigation controller then _your view controller has to be added to the navigation controller before viewDidLoad is called`.

In your first example, `viewDidLoad` was called when you added your view controller to a navigation controller (the second line above).

In your second example, `viewDidLoad` was called when you said `self.view` in the `initWithNibNamed:bundle:` method. Crucially, this is *before your view controller knows that it's going to be added to a navigation controller*. Therefore when you say `self.navigationController` it won't know which navigation controller you are talking about. It can't set the tint of something it doesn't know about yet!

In your first example, `viewDidLoad` is called *after* you have added your view controller to a navigation controller so when you say `self.navigationController` it knows which navigation controller you are talking about and can set the tint accordingly.

To test this yourself, put `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);` in your `viewDidLoad` method - I bet it outputs `nil` for the second example ;)

---

**FYI :**

You should always be doing the first example anyway - it will only create the image when it's needed and will let you unload the image in cases of low memory.

Comment: Thanks dean, but your assumption that I am calling these two views in a different way is not correct. The two examples above are the same view (just moving the "add image" from one place to another). This view is being called in the way I updated above.

Comment: BTW - when I do move the "add image" to the init method (second example above) the self.navigationController is indeed Null in viewDidLoad. No idea why....?

Comment: I've edited my question to explain more clearly what I mean. I'm right (sorry!) but I wasn't clear enough about the difference between a viewController and a view. Making a view controller doesn't make a view until it needs to. By you adding your image in the init method you are forcing it to call viewDidLoad too soon, before it knows which navigation controller you are trying to tint.

Comment: I totally see what you are saying...I had no idea that by init-ing, viewDidLoad was also called since we are not "showing" the view really. Is this happening because the init is calling: addSubview:? I mean, doesn calling addSubview: forces a call to viewdidload? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: anything that accesses the `view` property will cause it to be created :) In your `init` method, that's your `self.view` lines. In your first example, it will be some method somewhere inside apple's UI code when the navigation controller first starts to scroll the view onto the display.

Comment: (don't forget that it might be created more than once! If there's a low memory warning and the view isn't visible then it might get unloaded until it's next needed (the view controller stays, just the view gets released). When it's needed again (via a call to the `view` property!) it's recreated and `viewDidLoad` will be called again!)